# how can i get a menu of a parent taxonomy term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I know menus can be made of taxonomies, with taxonomy menu.

But the real huge problem i have is I CANT get taxonomy menu to show only one term's children in the taxonomy list.For example consider this taxonomy vocabulary:

```
creatures
-insects 
--ants 
--mosquitoes 
-mammals 
--rabit 
--dog
```

I want the taxonomy menu to show only mammals links, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

If your output should be a block or page, you could do it with Views.
If not, meaning you want to show only that part as a menu itself, you might want to consider writing your own query for it, and adding it as a hook in your template.php